# Display record from Crystal Report Details Section to Group Footer Per Group

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I have made a Crystal Report that group tenants per location. Each tenant are viewed by their current and previous month over all sales. There are instances where in a tenant's current sales status is CLOSED. What I need to do is filter all those tenant and put them in Group Footer PER GROUP / PER LOCATION. Currently I have a code that IS GETTING ALL the tenant's with closed status and display them in all pages.

**Code:**

Formula 1

```
 whilereadingrecords;
    stringvar strtitle;

    if ({@CurrentMonthNew}) = "CLOSED" and ({@PreviousMonthNew}) <> "CLOSED"
    THEN
    strtitle := strtitle + ">" + {spMSR;1.name}
```

Formula 2: the actual formula put outside section details as notes

```
evaluateafter({@notes});
stringvar strtitle;
```

How can I make the filtering per Location group. Please see this image for illustration of the report structure

[image]

Comment: @NuruSalihu badly need your expertise on this

Answer (score 1):

**UNTESTED** There could be some typos but this should get you started assuming I understand your question.

Formula 1 // place in Group 2 header and suppress so you cant see it

```
    Whilereadingrecords;
    global stringvar notes = "";
```

Formula 2 // place in detail section suppressed so you cant see it

```
Whilereadingrecords;
global stringvar notes;
if {table.yearcurrentfield} = 'CLOSED' then Notes := Notes & " " & {table.Notes field}
```

Formula 3 // in group 2 footer not suppressed

```
global stringvar notes;
```

Comment: Hi @CoSpringsGuy, I have tried your code and modified a little, Formula 3 should include evaluateafter({@notes}); before the global stringvar notes;, if not it will show nothing. Moreover, It is showing all the closed tenants in all reports. I thsould be per group (name) How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Based from the useful answer of CoSpringGuy, I have come up to the correct answer that work really well to my problem

USE the 3 WAY METHOD FORMULA

Formula 1: In Group Header

```
Whileprintingrecords;
stringvar strtitle := "";
numbervar var :=0;
```

Formula 2: In details Section, the condition you want

```
Whileprintingrecords;

stringvar strtitle;
numbervar var;

if ({@CurrentMonthNew}) = "CLOSED" and ({@PreviousMonthNew}) <> "CLOSED"
THEN
strtitle := strtitle   + ChrW(13) + {spMSR;1.name}
```

Formula 3: In Group Footer, the actual to be shown on the report

```
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar strtitle;
```

Use whileprintingrecord instead whilereadingrecord to work the per group function of producing note.